# GUI in Glade — application for Linux and Windows

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, glade

I have written a program in C, and I would like to make a GUI for it. I would like to use Glade because it is drag and drop. I am using Linux, but I would like the application that can be made to run on both Linux and Windows. Is it possible? And if it is, is there an option exporting the GUI for Windows using Linux?

Comment: @0d0a yes i saw Qt, i need something drag and drop in c

Answer (score 0):

After visiting the Glade [site](https://glade.gnome.org/),

I found that they have Windows binaries available. Here is a link to it:

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/glade/

I also found this:

http://wingtk.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I suppose that i have to install it and compile in windows for having an executable for windows?

Comment: I suggest you read their documentation for that, as it will provide the most accurate info.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the GCC compiler for Windows (mingw) on a Linux machine.

Afterwards, you can follow @Joe's link to get the Windows binary, and link them when you compile your program using mingw.

A quick Googling should give this link which covers step-by-step instructions on how to achieve this: http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45